# Does the argument of open_workbook() of xlrd module in Python takes dyanamic value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to put dynamic values as an arguments in open_workbook() function of xlrd but it is giving error.
My sample code is:

## ***********************************************************************

import xlrd,os
filepath=r'C:\Users\JJ\Desktop\JustForTest\2012_09_10'

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(filepath):

```
abc=files[0] # To convert List to string, files will be like ['Samplexyx.xls']

wb=xlrd.open_workbook(abc)
sh=wb.sheet_by_index(0)    
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    print(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

## ***********************************************************************

In the above code, the value of abc dynamically changes.
When I run above code, it is giving error as: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Samplexyx.xls'

I am new to using xlrd and Python. What should I do to dynamically open xls files using xlrd and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not looking in the right directory for the file

```
xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(filepath,abc))
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. I really appreciate that.